# Getting a GameObject to turn and move on a circle with a given speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a car to move by itself in Unity (C#). I can get the car to travel forwards by using:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the car to turn. I would like it to behave in the following way:

Imagine a car enters a cross roads (square of size 1x1 and negligible height) at point (0.5,0,0), i'd like it to exit the cross road at point (0,0,0.5) by simulating the turning of the vehicle in a circular pattern.

Does anybody know how to do this? I am getting problems with my mathematics.

As always, all help is appreciated :).

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: maybe you can set anchor behind the car , and move that point with rotation

Comment: define your path as a spline and use something like this http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Hermite_Spline_Controller

Answer (score -1):

First of all you gotta detect the car position >

```
> if (car.transform.position == 'WANTED POSITION') {
       while(car.transform.position.WANTEDSCALE != 'WANTED ROTATION'){
        car.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 'ROTATION SPEED' )); //rotatesZ
   }
}
```

WANTEDPOSITION = VECTOR 3 (0.5,0,0) as you wanted it

WANTEDSCALE = X/Y/Z = i dont know which one of them you want to rotate(probably z)

WANTED ROTATION = the rotation you would like to be at the end of the 'autopilot'

ROTATION SPEED = rotates at the speed you want... put it low and go testing until a number you want comes

Sorry for not coding everything right now... i just gave you the all logic... hit me up if you have any doubts or send me the whole code and maybe i will adjust it for you

Comment: What exactly is `=!` ?

Comment: `while` is a very **bad idea** in a frame based application. Using this your app will compeltely freeze until the rotation is done and only after that render the next frame ... so you get a freeze and then a jump to the final rotation as result. Also why should you compare `car.transform.position` to a target **rotation**?